# Google Maps SDK for iOS's map is not same as Google Map

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am useing Google maps SDK for iOS.I want to add marker some location.I get those Coordinates from  [Google Map](https://maps.google.com/).I found ATM Booths and other institution in [Google Map](https://maps.google.com/) With their specific icon but when i do this from app i don't get those.

In google map i fount an icon of ATM,Cafe and so many[image]

But not in my App.I am using  Google Maps SDK for iOS's [Version 1.6.1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases)

[image]

Can anyone describe it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the same problem last night when testing a small area.

The detail POIs (maybe when the zoomLevel of MapView is greater than 16?) is different between Yours.app and GoogleMaps.app

And it's easy to explain: Google need to keep the core competitiveness. In Maps business, data is everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't other places/landmarks outside of the defaults in the mapping api you will need to look at [Google places api](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?csw=1).

Comment: Is the ATM,Cafe these place markers are not default in Google Map?I mean does GMSMapView is not same as Google Map we see?

Comment: No the Google Map we see is just another Map API client application, they are free to add and remove things from the output they display just like everyone else.